# How do I set my JSON image to url format?

Tags: json, laravel

i want  to ask. how to set my json image to url format.

i have code to store my image like this :

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        if ($request->hasFile('objek_pict')) {
            $filePic   = $request->file('objek_pict');
            $extension = $filePic->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $fileName  = date('m-d-Y_', time()) . $request->nama_objek;
            // $filePic->move('/uluwatu_image/', $fileName . '.' . $extension, file_get_contents($request->file('objek_pict')->getRealPath()));
            $filePic->move('uluwatu_image/', $fileName . '.' . $extension);
        }

        $new_objek = new ObjekTable();
        $new_objek->nama_objek = $request->nama_objek;
        $new_objek->objek_lat = $request->objek_lat;
        $new_objek->objek_lng = $request->objek_lng;
        $new_objek->objek_pict = 'uluwatu_image/' . $fileName . '.' . $extension;
        $new_objek->objek_deskripsi = $request->objek_deskripsi;
        $new_objek->save();

        return redirect('masterdata')->with('success', 'Data Berhasil Ditambah');
    }
```

and this is how i get my json data
public function getDatajson(Request $request)
    {

```
    $lokasi = ObjekTable::select('id_objek as id', 'nama_objek as name', 'objek_lat as latitude', 'objek_lng as longitude', 'objek_deskripsi as description', 'objek_pict as image_object')->get();
}
```

this my json data link : https://aruluwatu.000webhostapp.com/api/json

this the picture : https://i.stack.imgur.com/aff6L.jpg

I want to make my json image show the url path like this:
https://aruluwatu.000webhostapp.com/uluwatu_image/04-15-2020_Rumah.jpg

*uluwatu_image/04-15-2020_Rumah.jpg (my saved image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this by using **Eloquent Accessors** that allow you to define custom attributes

in model **ObjekTable** define append attribute :

```
protected $appends = ['image_url'];
```

then set value image_url attribute on same model :

```
public function getImageUrlAttribute()
{
   return url(Storage::url( $this->objek_pict ));
}
```

now you get new attribute **image_url** on model instant contain the full image url

Comment: i set the getImageUrlAttribute() on my model right ? or in my controller ?

Comment: on your model 'ObjekTable '

Comment: and the 'image_url' i change to my webservice link? like this 
protected $appends = ['https://aruluwatu.000webhostapp.com'];

Comment: I have try it but it's not get the path. this is the output : [{"id":119,"name":"Ahayy","latitude":-8.80335,"longitude":115.1542,"description":"yeaa","images":"uluwatu_image\/04-21-2020_Ahayy.JPG","image_url":"https:\/\/aruluwatu.000webhostapp.com\/storage"}]

Comment: this is what i try just like you said : https://pastebin.com/jVxhXNvM

Comment: what is the name of column where you  store path of image?

Comment: the name is object_pict

Comment: but i see on the json output named : (images ) ?

Comment: yes, in my controller i make it to get my json data, like this :

public function getDatajson(Request $request)
    {
          
        return json_encode (ObjekTable::select('id_objek as id', 'nama_objek as name', 'objek_lat as latitude', 'objek_lng as longitude', 'objek_deskripsi as description', 'objek_pict as images')->get());
    }